# AWS EKS node stuck on EFS mount point

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I have configured EKS cluster (1.20) with 5 nodes and deployed a lot of helm charts, some applications needed some shared storage like EFS so I have configured it as well and mounted to the specific folders using PV and PVC which has been provided by *efs-csi-controller*.

everything worked very well for more than 6 months, but in the last days I noticed that two Nodes has SOMETIMES taints as NotScheduled/NotExecuted which means that node is not ready and new deployments are not working for me because nodes are not available during that time.

I found that only those two nodes have problems with executing command "df -h" (shell stuck) so I suppose that this is the problem with EFS which is not reachable, do you have any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: have you tried to ping efs from the pods or have ou changed the efs while the pods are 'up'? df -h gets stuck when you remove efs or change it with another one without first unmounting it.(My experience)

Comment: @Riz I am connected to EKS Node via SSM and I cannot execute even df -h, when I execute this command on pods, everything works fine

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant nodes and not pods. If the nodes are not in autoscaling group and if you have the possibilty to restart, I would suggest to do so. It has happened to me while changing the efs and changing the record on route53(we use custom names for the efs) and the easiest soultion I have found for this is to restart the node. Not sure why it has happened suddenly without you making any changes to efs. By the way `kubectl describe node 'node'` doesn't give you any meaningful info?

Comment: same issue here. recently ran into this issue and couldn’t tind anything useful on the describe node